# How can I convert a git bare mirror repository into a regular bare repository

Tags: git

As of now we have a master - slave setup where we have shared bare repositories on the master side and bare mirror repositories on the slave side
I managed to make the mirror repositories to get shared repositories by using git init
Now we are planning on switching the roles, this means the master will be the slave and have mirror repositories instead of just bare repositories, I think I found the solution for that
The question is what do I have to do to change the bare mirror repositories into regular bare repositories?
Is it sufficient to change the config file or do I have to do more than that?

Answer (score 6):

I'm pretty sure (and confirmed with a quick test on a local repository) the only difference between a `--mirror` and a `--bare` clone is that the `--mirror` clone contains these lines under the `[remote "origin"]` section in its `config` file:

```
fetch = +refs/*:refs/*
mirror = true
```

Removing those should be all you need to do.